# perform asynchronous operations inside as a constant variable

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, react-native, es6-promise

I have one functional component

```
import { DEFAULT_LANGUAGE} from './translations';
import React, { useState } from 'react';

export const Welcome= () => {
    const [appLanguage, setAppLanguage] = useState(DEFAULT_LANGUAGE);
    console.log(appLanguage);
};
```

translations.js

```
   import AsyncStorage from '@react-native-async-storage/async-storage';

    export const DEFAULT_LANGUAGE= async () => {
       try {
           const response = await AsyncStorage.getItem('appLanguage');
           if(response){
               return response;
           }
           else{
               return 'English';
           }
       }
       catch (e) {
           return 'English';
       }
    }
```

appLanguage returns promise object instead of value. How can I perform asynchronous operations inside as a constant variable?

Comment: `DEFAULT_LANGUAGE` is a function. You need to call it. To run an async function when your component mounts, use `useEffect` with an empty dependency array.

Comment: Can you  do just `useState(await DEFAULT LANGUAGE())`? (You'd probably need to make `async Welcome` as well)

Comment: @Grzegorz - No, component functions are rquired to be synchronous. You can't use `await` in a synchronous function.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder what if you made `const getDefLang = async () => await DEFAULT_LANGUAGE()` and used that in `useState` ?

Comment: @Grzegorz - Same problem, `async` functions always return promises, so you'd get a promise, not the value. [You **can't** get an asynchronous result synchronously](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-do-i-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call).

Answer (score 1):

You **can't** make `DEFAULT_LANGUAGE` contain the fulfillment value rather than a promise **unless** you make loading the module exporting it wait until that asynchronous operation is complete. So you either:

1. Delay completion of that module's load until the value is available
2. Make it a promise and handle that where you use it

#### 1 - Delaying module load using top-level `await`

You can only do that if your environment supports [top-level `await`](https://reactjs.org/docs/context.html), which many do now.

To use that to delay loading of that module until the asynchronous request is complete, you'd do this:

```
export const DEFAULT_LANGUAGE = await (async () => {
    try {
        const response = await AsyncStorage.getItem('appLanguage');
        if (response) {
            return response;
        } else {
            return 'English';
        }
    } catch (e) {
        return 'English';
    }
})();
```

Which can also be written as:

```
export const DEFAULT_LANGUAGE = await (async () => {
    let language;
    try {
        language = await AsyncStorage.getItem("appLanguage");
    } catch (e) {
    }
    return language || "English";
})();
```

or even:

```
export const DEFAULT_LANGUAGE = await AsyncStorage.getItem("appLanguage")
    .catch(() => null)
    .then(language => language || "English");
```

That does the asynchronous work, waits for it, and then allows the module load to occur.

Naturally, delaying module load like that may not be the best choice, it's **very** situation-dependent. But it's your only option **if** you need `DEFAULT_LANGUAGE` to be the fulfillment value, not a promise.

#### 2 - Making it a promise and waiting for it

Right now, you've made `DEFAULT_LANGUAGE` a function. Nothing calls it. Instead, call it and store the returned promise:

```
export const DEFAULT_LANGUAGE_PROMISE = (async () => {
   try {
       const response = await AsyncStorage.getItem('appLanguage');
       if (response) {
           return response;
       } else {
           return 'English';
       }
   } catch (e) {
       return 'English';
   }
})();
```

Then, when using it, wait for promise fulfillment:

```
import { DEFAULT_LANGUAGE_PROMISE} from './translations';
import React, { useState } from 'react';

export const Welcome = () => {
    const [appLanguage, setAppLanguage] = useState(null);
    useEffect(() => {
        // We don't have to worry about rejection, because you've set it
        // up not to reject
        DEFAULT_LANGUAGE_PROMISE.then(setAppLanguage);
    }, []);
    // ...
};
```

Note that `Welcome`'s rendering will have to handle the fact that `appLanguage` will be `null` at first in this scenario.

You might want to make your main entry-point component handle this, and then provide it to all components in the tree via [context](https://reactjs.org/docs/context.html). There are all sorts of different ways to spin this.